# Slot management and discovery with a twist

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch

I am trying to build discovery flow for a company and stuck at one place. This company's sellable entity is doctor's appointment slots.

Each slot has following attributes

- startTime
- endTime
- doctorId

Each doctor has following attributes

- doctorId
- doctor's location (latitude, longitude)

Also each doctor has another table for ratings/reviews

Now when someone searches, user should land on page which should have following characteristics -

- List of all doctors
- Ability to sort doctors by ratings/location
- Ability to apply filter for particular time range slot

However now since sorting is applied on a different entity (doctors) and filtering is applied on a different entity (slots), I am not able to figure out how to do this.

I tried following approaches -

- Denormalize schema and associate rating and location with each slot. This solution is not scalable. Also once a slot is created, any further changes in location/rating will not reflect.
- Make doctor as my primary entity and store all related slots in one big JSON document and then use elastic-search/MongoDB for queries. This solution also seems non scalable since number of slots will keep on increasing every day, thereby increasing document size indefinitly

Please help

Comment: What all things are you showing in doctor's list. Can a Doctor have more than one range slot?

Comment: @Richa Yes one doctor can have more than one range slot